# How to get the node attribute values from XML using Java XML parser?

Tags: java, xml

```
<Files>
    <File Name="D:/temp/OpId_63_7b126c8d-f90a-402b-9902-786c7995314f/35f9cdf8-f6cc-4c9d-b0e5-cc21c1842765" />
    <File Name="D:/temp/PPPPOpId_63_7b126c8d-f90a-402b-9902-786c7995314f/35f9cdf8-f6cc-4c9d-b0e5-cc21c1842765" />
</Files>
```

From the above XML I want two file names like this:

```
D:/temp/OpId_63_7b126c8d-f90a-402b-9902-786c7995314f/35f9cdf8-f6cc-4c9d-b0e5-cc21c1842765
D:/temp/PPPPOpId_63_7b126c8d-f90a-402b-9902-786c7995314f/35f9cdf8-f6cc-4c9d-b0e5-cc21c1842765
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [javax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/package-summary.html), you could extract the data via xpath queries with something like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(stream);

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

String name1 = (String)xpath.evaluate("/Files/File[1]/@Name", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
String name2 = (String)xpath.evaluate("/Files/File[2]/@Name", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

This is assuming your XML is loading from an inputstream in the *stream* variable. If you already have the XML as a string, you could convert that to a stream like this:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlstring.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

You could also load the XML directory from a url with:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(url);
```

Note that you'll need at least these imports:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
```

Answer (score 3):

using DOM XML parser

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

then,

```
File filesXML = new File("/files.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(filesXML);


NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("File");

for (int i= 0; i< nList.getLength(); i++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(i);

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {



        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("File: " + eElement.getAttribute("Name"));
        }
}
```

[Reference](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just doing that simple stuff, have a look at any Java XML parsing reference.

For a good XML Parser take `JAXB` with something like this (untested):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Files")
public class FilesXML {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="File")
    @XmlAttribute(name="Name")
    private String filename;
}
```

Then marshall and unmarshall as you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DocumentBuilderFactory docbuilderfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder docbuilder = docbuilderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document document = docbuilder.parse(fileName);
   String xpath = "//File";
   NodeList testConfig = org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI.selectNodeList(document, xpath);
   count = testConfig.getLength();
   String fileNames[] = new String[count];
   int rows = 0;
   while (rows < count) {
     Node row = testConfig.item(rows);
     if (row.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        AttributeMap map = (AttributeMap) row.getAttributes();
        int attrCount = map.getLength();
        int j = 0;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        while (j < attrCount) {
             props.put(map.item(j).getNodeName(),map.item(j).getNodeValue().trim());
             j++;
        }
        fileNames[rows] = props.getProperty("Name"); // Maniuplate The props object
     }
    rows++;
  }
```

As per the above code, the array object, fileNames has the all the file names available in the xml file